# jconsole not connecting to local process

Tags: java, jconsole

I seek your help in solving below issue . Thanks in advance !

I started intellij and one sample program in it then I started jconsole from command prompt .

I can see my program listed down in jconsole but when I select it and try to connect , it never succeeds .

The screen "connecting to " "You are currently being ... "  doesn't move ahead .

Here are the screen shots

[image]

I am passing below program arguments
**-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost**

*Here are my env variable*  , I am using windows 10

```
IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3.2\bin;

JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172

OS=Windows_NT
Path=C:\PrgogamData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Strawberry\c\bin;C:\Strawberry\perl\site\bin;C:\Strawberry\perl\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_281\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_281\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_172\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin;C:\Users\<myuserame>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3.2\bin;

PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC

platformcode=KV

TEMP=C:\Users\<myuserame>\AppData\Local\Temp

TMP=C:\Users\<myuserame>\AppData\Local\Temp
```